# How do I populate a column that already has URL's with values from 2 other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently developing a report in SQL Server. Let's say I have 3 columns.

```
FirstName | LastName | URL's
----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
Tiffany   | Smith    | www.example.com/accountname=%3Dtiffany%7Lsmith
```

The format of the URL will always be:

```
www.example.com/accountname=%3Dname%7Lname
```

How would I populate the URL column with values from `FirstName` and `LastName` like the example above?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and the results you would like to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using concatenate:

```
create table #temp
(
firstname varchar(50),
lastname  varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp (firstname, lastname) values
('tiffany', 'smith'),
('john', 'doe')

select 
firstname
, lastname
, concat('www.example.com/accountname=%3D', firstname, '%7L', lastname) as 'url'
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
declare @firstname varchar(10) = 'hello'

declare @lastname varchar(10) = 'there'

select 'www.example.com/accountname=%3D'+@firstname+'%7L'+@lastname as url
```

the URL that is return is this

www.example.com/accountname=%3Dhello%7Lthere

simply replace the variables with your column names

Comment: I'm assuming that the URL column does not exist and you can derive it as above. Even if it does exist.. you can ignore it and derive the column for the report this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(FirstName , LastName , [URL's])
AS
(
SELECT 'Tiffany', 'Smith', 'www.example.com/accountname=%3D%7L'  Union all 
SELECT 'john', 'doe',Null
)
SELECT FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,ISNULL(STUFF(STUFF([URL's], CHARINDEX('%3D', [URL's]) + 3, 0, FirstName), 
            CHARINDEX('%7L', STUFF([URL's], CHARINDEX('%3D', [URL's]) + 3, 0, FirstName)),
                LEN(LastName), '%7L' + LastName), 'NA') AS [URL's]
FROM cte
```

OutPut

```
FirstName   LastName    [URL's]
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Tiffany     Smith       www.example.com/accountname=%3DTiffany%7LSmith
john        doe         NA
```